# Как сделать экспорт данных из таблицы в бд (toad for oracle)

Tags: select, export, oracle12c, procedure

Хочу написать скрипт для выгрузки данных с запроса , чтобы потом создать процедуру и при вызове процедуры , выгружались данные в sql файл